# Link files so they get edited equal

Tags: php, authentication, registration

I have mage a login system on my website. I've done it so when someone signs up, they get their own folder with a file in it. Yhe file is called *profile.php*. The *profile*.php file is directed in the root folder, and is copied into the users folder.

Here is a small part of my code:

```
try {
    $path = "users/".$row['ID']."/";
    if(!is_dir($path)){
        mkdir($path);
    }
    copy('profile.php',$path . 'profile.php');
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    die('error');
}
```

I wondered if it was possible to change all the *profile.php* files in all the foldesr at once when i edit the root file.

Does anybody know?

Comment: Sure it would be possible, but that's a maintainance nightmare. Better create your App so that you don't have to do this.

Comment: Better to go through the headache of setting up a sql database now than the having to deal with storing information the way you're planning to

Comment: You don’t need to copy a file for each user’s profile. Have a single **profile.php** script that takes a parameter (say user ID), fetch the corresponding user’s profile from the database and display it. PHP is a dynamic scripting language, so make it do dynamic things. Copying a script per user isn’t dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I acctually managed to solve the problem by myself.
I created i new file called **profilepage.php**, and the code in this file is:

```
<?php
    require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/profile.php');
```

Then i edited the register file so it copies the **profilepage.php** instead.

```
try {
    $path = "users/".$row['ID']."/";
    if(!is_dir($path)){
        mkdir($path);
    }
    copy('profilepage.php',$path . 'profilepage.php');
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
die('error');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it that manually using a the sed linux command like that

```
find /users -name \profile.php  -exec sed -i "s/oldword/newword/g" {} \;
```

**/users** this is the path

**profile.php** is the file name

**oldword** the old text you want to remove

**newword** the new text yu want to add

**find program** searches a given directory (and its subdirectories) for files based on a variety of attributes. 
you better off using php and mysql to edit the pages instead of such hard way 
what if next time you want to add text and after that yu want replace another it will be hard